# How to Redraw or Refresh a screen

Tags: c#, wpf, refresh, folderbrowserdialog

I am working on a wpf application. Here I need to use System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog in my Wpf application.

```
        System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog openFolderBrowser = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();

        openFolderBrowser.Description = "Select Resource Path:";
        openFolderBrowser.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
        if (openFolderBrowser.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //some logic
            openFolderBrowser.Dispose();
        }
```

I launch a FolderBrowserDialog, select a Folder and click OK, and then I launch another System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog, My problem is when I select a Folder and click OK in this FolderBrowserDialog, the shadow of FolderBrowserDialog remains on the screen(means my screen doesn't refresh). I need to minimize or resize it in order to remove the shadow of FolderBrowserDialog. How can I solve this issue?
Any help plz?

#### Edit:

I found the solution. I called OnRender method on my wpf Window and it worked for me. It redraws everythign on the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call [InvalidateVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual.aspx) method to refresh UI.

Comment: Thanks, It gave me the way to solve my problem. I have updated the question with the way I solved my problem.

Comment: OnRender will consume huge of CPU on my machine, I use this method after ShowDialog is return.

Answer (score 1):

on a form code

```
 Update();
```

refreshes screen and updates ui.

We are using winforms so Update() is a basic function that redraws the window content. so you may use it directly from a form. The basic usage could be a timer which updates a label on a screen. when timer ticks you update the label:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
t.Interval = 1000; // specify interval time as you want 
t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
t.Start();

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  label1.text = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss")); 
  Update(); //this will refresh the form and label's text is updated.
}
```

otherwise label1.text will never change.

Comment: I think this needs a little more info for someone else to find this answer useful

Comment: Update() is no standard .NET method. You should point to the correct implementation.

Comment: hope this edit make it clear ono2012 and Marcel Grüger